# Subset rows with pattern match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a tab delimited file with columns formatted like this:

```
cat    1/1:127:59:0:1    0/0:.:78:0:.,.,.:1    0/0:.:64:0:.,.,.:     
cat    0/0:.:53:0:.,.,.:1    0/1:.:53:0:.,.,.:0    0/0:.:57:0:.,.,.:1
dog    1/0:127:59:0:1    1/1:.:78:0:.,.,.:1    0/0:.:64:0:.,.,.:1
```

I need to subset all the rows that have one or more column that starts with "1/1:" and ends with ":1", giving the following file:

```
cat    1/1:127:59:0:1    0/0:.:78:0:.,.,.:1    0/0:.:64:0:.,.,.:0
dog    1/0:127:59:0:1    1/1:.:78:0:.,.,.:1    0/0:.:64:0:.,.,.:1
```

I have tried using grep and regular expressions, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

NB. The actual file is very large

Comment: So you only have to say `[ ]1/1:[^ ]*:1( |$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try

```
^.+?\s1\/1.+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/I5oUAB/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` a BRE should be like this:

```
grep ' 1/1:[^ ]*:1\( \|$\)' file
```

You only need to check if one column starts and ends with desired delimiters.

Note that there is a space at the beginning of regex.